# BIOS troubleshooting - how it become corrupted?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

Recently I was repairing two computers: 8+ years old core 2 duo, and 1 year old core i3. Both had problems with booting. First one: no video output, no beeps, leds & fans on, second one: no video output, no beeps, leds & fans on, keep rebooting every 3sec.

In both cases resetting the BIOS (remove battery) solved the problem.

Now I started to wonder what can cause BIOS corruption? There was no power failure etc. One day you normally shut down your computer, next day it won't boot... weird

Comment: Faulty/failing battery, static electricity, power spikes, electromagnetics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware changes, most likely, such as changing memory, video cards, or the like. For example, if the onboard video is disabled in the BIOS, it won't boot without an external video card. If the voltages or timings were customized for the RAM that was in before, it may not POST with different RAM. And so on.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. But I'm talking about situation where are no configuration changes and BIOS get somehow corrupted